# Comparing the results from lpSolve to linprog, is it a problem in implementation?

Tags: r, python-3.x, scipy, linear-programming, lpsolve

I would like to minimize a linear programming system with linear constraints "equalities".

The system summarized in the following code "Python 3"

```
>>> obj_func = [1,1,1]
>>> const = [[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]
>>> constraints= np.reshape(const, (-1, 3))
>>> constraints
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
>>> rhs = [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168, 1.0]
```

Using `scipy.optimization.linprg`:

```
   >>> res = linprog(obj_func, constraints, rhs, method="interior-point", options={"disp":True})
>>> res
     con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 1.4722956444515663e-09
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([0.44981622, 0.44981622, 0.10036756, 1.        ])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([4.34463075e-10, 4.34463075e-10, 6.03369494e-10])
```

The same system summarized in R and minimized using `lpSolve`:

```
> obj.func = c(1,1,1)
> constraints = matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1), nrow= 4, byrow = TRUE)
> rhs = c(0.4498162+0i, 0.4498162+0i, 0.1003676+0i, 1.0000000+0i)
> f.dir = c("=","=","=","=")
>
> res = lp("min",obj.func,constraints,f.dir,rhs,compute.sens=FALSE)
> res
Success: the objective function is 1
```

As detailed above, the results are not close to each other although it is the same system so I did the same work for other systems but the results are also far.

My question: I know it is not necessary that every LP has a unique solution but I think they should produce close values ! In my case, I tried to minimize many systems using both solvers but the results are too far. For example,

```
First system: linprog gave 1.4722956444515663e-09 while lpSolve gave 1
Another system: linprog gave 1.65952852061376e-11 while lpSolve gave 0.8996324
Another system: linprog gave 3.05146726445553e-12 while lpSolve gave 0.8175745
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are solving different models.

```
res = linprog(obj_func, constraints, rhs, method="interior-point", options={"disp":True})
```

means

```
res = linprog(obj_func, A_ub=constraints, b_ub=rhs, method="interior-point", options={"disp":True})
```

effecting in constraints:

```
x0 <= 0.4498162176582741
...
```

instead of

```
x0 == 0.4498162176582741
```

So linprog is using **inequalities** only while lpsolve is using **equalities** only (without me checking if `f.dir = c("=","=","=","=")` is doing what i think it's doing; but the result shows this more or less).

The linprog-result:

```
x: array([4.34463075e-10, 4.34463075e-10, 6.03369494e-10])
```

is a typical zero-vector output of an interior-point method (only approximates integral solutions)! In contrast to [commercial solvers like Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/crossover.html), there is no crossover step.

Be careful when reading the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog) (which contain this information).